# Storyboard: can't drag view to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I'm new to iOS, I'm following this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/. I just drag and dropped a `Page View Controller` to the storyboard, and tried to drag an `Image View` into it, but it bounce back, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIPageViewController is a container view controller, so you can't put individual views in one in Interface Builder.  You need to create one or more individual content view controllers and control-drag from the page view controller to the page content controller and then put actual content in the page content controller.

Walk through the tutorial again, but this time note the references to "page content view controller"

Answer (score 8):

When manipulating the content of ViewControllers in storyboards, the zoomlevel must be set to 100%. You might want to check this (simply doubleclick on the ViewController).

Comment: I already tried this. Maybe I can't drag and drop UIView into PageViewController?

Comment: Sorry, kind of missed the part with the 'Page View Controller' ;) You cannot add views to it in storyboard. Please refer to David's answer

Comment: This is why I couldn't drop _anything_ on a ViewController, thank you.